# No Overflow Button

Tags: android, android-appbarlayout

I have a Navigation Drawer application that is not displaying the overflow button. I have checked and my device does not have a menu button, so it should appear but Im not sure why it isn't appearing. Some of my code below

Main Layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_brgo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_brgo"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_brgo_drawer"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

App Bar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.tble.brgo.BRGO">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:theme="@style/AppTheme"
>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragmentcontainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.tble.brgo.BRGO">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/S14273"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="High School"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/S14276"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Middle School"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/S14274"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Hillside"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/S14271"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Eisenhower"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/S14278"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Van Holten"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/S14277"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Milltown"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/S14275"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="J.F.K. Primary"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/S14272"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Hamilton"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/S14269"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Crim Primary"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/S14268"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Bradely Gardens"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/S14264"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Adamsville"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

</menu>
```

Main Java file

```
package com.tble.brgo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import layout.Calendar;
import layout.News;
import layout.StudentID;
import layout.Temp;
import layout.Websites;
import layout.About;

public class BRGO extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_brgo);
        News initial = new News();
        FragmentTransaction transfer = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transfer.replace(R.id.fragmentcontainer, initial).commit();
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        navigationView.setItemTextAppearance(R.style.itemFont);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
    public void takePic(View v) {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        StudentID temp = (StudentID) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentcontainer);
        temp.takePicture();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.brgo, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        SharedPreferences sharedPref =  getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.S14273) {
         editor.putInt("School", 14273);
            editor.commit();
            return true;
        }
        else if(id == R.id.S14276){
            editor.putInt("School", 14276);
            editor.commit();
            return true;
        }
        else if(id == R.id.S14274){
            editor.putInt("School", 14274);
            editor.commit();
            return true;
        }
        else if(id == R.id.S14271){
            editor.putInt("School", 14271);
            editor.commit();
            return true;
        }
        else if(id == R.id.S14278){
            editor.putInt("School", 14278);
            editor.commit();
            return true;
        }
        else if(id == R.id.S14277){
            editor.putInt("School", 14273);
            editor.commit();
            return true;
        }
        else if(id == R.id.S14275){
            editor.putInt("School", 14275);
            editor.commit();
            return true;
        }
        else if(id == R.id.S14272){
            editor.putInt("School", 14272);
            editor.commit();
            return true;
        }
        else if(id == R.id.S14269){
            editor.putInt("School", 14269);
            editor.commit();
            return true;
        }
        else if(id == R.id.S14268){
            editor.putInt("School", 14268);
            editor.commit();
            return true;
        }
        else if(id == R.id.S14264){
            editor.putInt("School", 14264);
            editor.commit();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        Fragment fragment;
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.nav_News:
                fragment = News.newInstance();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_Calendar:
                fragment = Calendar.newInstance();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_Websites:
                fragment = Websites.newInstance();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_About:
                fragment = About.newInstance();
                break;
            default:
                fragment = Temp.newInstance();
                break;
        }
        FragmentTransaction transfer = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transfer.replace(R.id.fragmentcontainer,fragment).addToBackStack("tag").commit();
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: orderInCategory="100" in  all menu items. by this logic only one menu item will be shown. Make orderInCategory="100","200","300"... for the menu items

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overflow button has disappeared](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281317/overflow-button-has-disappeared)

Comment: Please edit your questions to bump to the front page. Don't repost

Answer (score 0):

In onCreateOptionMenu
Retun :

```
return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
```

Instead of return true.

Comment: That has no effect